# calling method of object of object with call_user_func

Tags: php, function, dynamic

consider this simple scenario:

```
$this->method($arg1, $arg2);
```

Solution:

```
call_user_func_array(array($this,'method'), array($arg1, $arg2));
```

consider this scenario:

```
$this->object->method($arg1, $arg2);
```

Should this solution work?

```
call_user_func_array(array($this->object,'method'), array($arg1, $arg2));
```

Or should this work?

```
    call_user_func_array(array($this, 'object','method'), array($arg1, $arg2));
```

Edit:
Will try/catch works for SOAP exception, triger while using call_user_func?

```
  try {
    $soap_res = call_user_func_array(array($this->service,'getBanana'), array(0, 10));
} catch (SoapFault $fault) {
    die($fault->faultstring)
}
```

Comment: I reckon this is a question/answer site... but the notion of running both solutions to see which one works never occured to you?

Comment: It's a test question sponsored by SO, and you have multiple choices. Answers should be in the form of letters A,B or C.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

This should work:

```
call_user_func_array(array($this->object,'method'), array($arg1, $arg2));
```

The first argument is a [callback type](http://php.net/callback), containing an object reference and a method name.

Comment: To pass the arguments automatically you can use `func_get_args()`. For example: `call_user_func_array(array($this,'method'), func_get_args())`

Comment: But would that not provoke the first argument (the callback array) to also be passed?

Answer (score 7):

Here's a hackish variant, might be useful to someone:

```
$method_name_as_string = 'method_name';
$this->$method_name_as_string($arg1, $arg2);
```

This uses the PHP variable-variables. Ugly as hell, but not particularly uglier than the others...