# Parametrized query unknown total params

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

i am using safemysql class for parametrized queries https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql.
Usualy, when preparing a query, it goes like this:

```
$entries = $db->getAll("SELECT * FROM table WHERE age = ?i AND name = ?s ",$age,$name);
```

This kind of queries where i know in advance the total number of parametres to be parsed are pretty straight fwd but it seems i am stacked at queries where I do not know how many parametres I will be using - eg. a search form:

What I would like to do, is parametrize the folowing query:

```
if($_POST['nameparts']){

    $parts = explode(' ',$_POST['nameparts']);

    foreach((array)$parts as $part){

        $q .= " AND ( `name` LIKE '%".$part."%' OR `firstname` LIKE '%".$part."%' ) ";

    }

    if($_POST['age'])
        $q .= " AND `age` = '".$_POST['age']."' ";

    $entries = $dbs->getAll("SELECT * FROM table WHERE 1 = 1 ".$q." ");
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why can't you use [PDO](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) or `mysqli` instead?

Comment: `$_POST['age']` is still open to sql injection. also wont `1 = 1` just return all the rows.. confused

Comment: I know. I haven't tried to parametrize anything in the example. Right now I am doing some escaping to the data but that is not the subject here.
1=1 should return all rows if $q is not set. Else 1=1 helps in adding a $q that starts with "AND";

Comment: Solution: build the *query text dynamically with placeholders*, and then call the function with an *array applied* to bind the values. That is, *do not encode [user] values into the query text itself*.

Comment: As you can see, I know how to create a parametrised query with exact set of parameters. I am presenting the old one just because the total number of parametres is variable. If I would've used placeholders instead of '".$variable."' nobody would have understand what I want.

Comment: Sure I would have: this question isn't novel or unique. The answer you received actually stems from limiting the question to include such query text generation with data-in-the-text and does *not* show placeholders being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with any other SQL query with user-supplied data, to handle this in a truly safe way (or rather to push off the work where it belongs), [**use placeholders**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/2864740).

Yup, let's *start* with that goal and *not lose sight of it* - if the query text *contains [user-supplied] data* then the code is in *violation* of one of [safemysql's](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql) (and safe SQL usage) tenants and the following is *not* necessarily true anymore!

> [safemysql is] safe because every dynamic query part [or "bit of user data"] goes into query via placeholder.

The solution is then to build the *query text with placeholders* and the *data array* dynamically - but *separately*. At no time is the DQL (SQL syntax) and the data mixed. It is this *separation* (and the guarantee of the lower levels) that guarantees that there is no [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) when this approach is followed.

```
$data = array();
$q = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE 1 = 1 ";
if($_POST['nameparts']){
    $parts = explode(' ',$_POST['nameparts']);
    foreach((array)$parts as $part){            
        $q .= " AND (`name` LIKE ?s OR `firstname` LIKE ?s )";
        $data[] = '%' . $part . '%'; // add one for each replacement
        $data[] = '%' . $part . '%';
    }
    if($_POST['age']) {
        $q .= " AND `age` = ?i ";
        $data[] = $_POST['age'];
    }
}
```

And now we have the *query text with placeholders* and an *array of the data* to bind. Yippee, we are *almost there*! Now, create the array that will be passed and [invoke the method supplying an array for the parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980708/calling-method-of-object-of-object-with-call-user-func).

```
$params = array($q);
$params = array_merge($params, $data);

$entries = call_user_func_array(array($dbs, 'getAll'), $params);
```

And, finished!

Comment: Damn!!!!!
I have just modified my safemysql class and was very proud of myself. But this is just **Wow!** :)
call_user_func_array(array($dbs, 'getAll'), $params);

Comment: `call_user_func_array` looks like overkill in this case. Anyway this shows that there is design flaw in https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql. May be someone will create a patch to it.

Comment: Btw. There is open issue describing this problem: https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql/issues/18

Comment: @IvanNevostruev I maintain that it's not overkill - and in fact, the "correct" method in this case, for the reasons outlined above. While it would be nice if the safemysql methods had a form which took an array of arguments (and perhaps even named arguments), the approach of calling a variadic function with an array is functional, clean, and simple. It would be trivially to create an appropriate `getAllEx` wrapper method, if desired (to maintain backwards compatibility with binding of `?a` it would need to be a separate method).

Comment: @user2864740 I believe correct method will be use standard `PDO` module or extend `safemysql` with appropriately named method. `call_user_func_array` solution works, but reader of the code will be confused why it was used. Mainly because its semantics is different from "flatten array as parameters". Also code analysis tools will have hard time to tell which method is called here. So I would not recommend this to use in production quality code.

Comment: @IvanNevostruev A code analysis tool that doesn't understand `call_user_func_array(array(obj, 'method').., ..)` should be suspect, and any confused reader/programmer should be taught a new tool. As far as the use of PDO [directly] - *why*? For better or worse, this library was chosen (and it uses mysqli underneath which is "sufficient"). I am not opposed to wrapping or extending with `getAllEx`, etc, but it might internally use this same approach to call the original `getAll` method. Consider with a wrapper, everything being the same: `$dbs->getAllEx($q, $data)`.

Comment: `if($anum == 1){
   if(is_array($args['0'])){
     $args = $args['0'];
     $anum = count($args);
     }
  }`
And that's the way the class could cover array arguments.

Comment: @valiD While this would work in many cases, such an approach requires changing the safemysql API because it understands `?a` (array) bindings already.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like safemysql supports variable number of placeholders (otherwise you could build array of parameters in parallel with your query). But you can use methods like `escapeString(...)`. It'll give you the same level of safety, but not so elegant. For example:

```
$q .= " AND `age` = ".$dbs->escapeInt($_POST['age')]." ";
```

Comment: That is what I wanted to know. I was sure I can create an array of params and I did not know how to.

Comment: @valiD You can and likely *should* create an array of parameters. While this will work and provide some level of sanity, it does not do so.

Comment: Yes, this is what I'll recommend to do in "normal" situation (like PDO). But I couldn't find how to pass that array as placeholders for safemysql. Looks like it always use `func_get_args()` to get list of arguments https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql/blob/master/safemysql.class.php#L261